# Can't select a row in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I followed the instructions http://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html and wrote the following code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var editor_basic = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
      ajax: "/webmaster/wordbag/treeForm",
      table: "#wordbag_basic_table",
      fields: [{
              label: "wordbag",
              name: "wordbag"
          }
      ]
  });

  $('#wordbag_basic_table').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
      editor_basic.inline( this );
  });

var basic = [
    {'DT_RowId': 1 ,
    'wordbag':  'hello',
    'parentID': 4,
    },
];

var datatable_basic = $('#wordbag_basic_table').DataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    data: basic,
    language: {
        paginate: {
            previous: '‹',
            next:     '›'
        },
        aria: {
            paginate: {
                previous: 'Previous',
                next:     'Next'
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
      {
      data: null,
      defaultContent: '',
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      orderable: false,
      },
      { data: "wordbag" },
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      selector: 'td:first-child',
    },
    buttons: [
      { extend: "create", editor: editor_basic },
      { extend: "edit",  editor: editor_basic },
      { extend: "remove", editor: editor_basic },
    ]
});
```

But when I click on the first column like a select box, the row couldn't be selected.So I can't edit or delete the row. Could you help me figure out?

Comment: Did you include dataTables.select.min.js and dataTables.editor.min.js on your page as well?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is too late but it will be usefull for future users.

The first step you should do is to create a quite simple html file where you include all the css and jss you use exactly on your current project. There are :

- datatable css
- datatable select css (or other extensions css)
- jquery js
- datatable js
- datatable select js (or other extensions js)

Then you test if it works. I'm pretty sure it will not work and the reason is **the versions** of those stuffs you use.

So you should find which file you should change. They don't play well together. For me, I swicth to the last jquery datatable js and it works.